# Web Deploy \ TFS - Ignores settings and deploys to same server no matter the parameters passed

Tags: webdeploy

I have an application that needs to be deployed to two different servers (environments).

I have two environments on two separate servers, server1 and server2.

Both servers have different IIS Manager user accounts and passwords configured.

The builds however all happen on server1 and it appears that no matter what settings I pass via the build definition, everything gets deployed to server 1.

I can publish to server2 manually from the Publish command in VS2010 but this needs to be automated in TFS.

This used to work fine but then started happening a couple of weeks ago.

How can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, although I followed the IIS generated settings file, I had to set the MSDeployPublishMethod to WMSVC (it was set to MSDeploy). I can't tell you why this works and the other doesn't but this is how I solved it. If anyone has any details on where one can find out more about the various Web Deploy settings please advise!